# Google map v2 application Show error

Tags: android, google-maps

I a wrote google map program step by step from the Google developer tutorial.
But when I run on a smart phone or in `avd` it crashes. When I comment out `setContent(r.activity_main)` the app runs and show empty page but in normal state with `setContent` app it crashes!

My Log cat:

```
06-05 10:59:10.028: E/AndroidRuntime(387): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.please/com.example.please.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class fragment
06-05 10:59:10.028: E/AndroidRuntime(387):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
06-05 10:59:10.028: E/AndroidRuntime(387):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
06-05 10:59:10.028: E/AndroidRuntime(387):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-05 10:59:10.028: E/AndroidRuntime(387):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
06-05 10:59:10.028: E/AndroidRuntime(387):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-05 10:59:10.028: E/AndroidRuntime(387):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-05 10:59:10.028: E/AndroidRuntime(387):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-05 10:59:10.028: E/AndroidRuntime(387):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 10:59:10.028: E/AndroidRuntime(387):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-05 10:59:10.028: E/AndroidRuntime(387):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-05 10:59:10.028: E/AndroidRuntime(387):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
```

---

my XML file:

```
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

my java file:

```
package com.example.please;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }
}
```

Comment: paste your xml file here

Comment: you should use supportmapfragment and your activity should extend fragmentactivity

Comment: I Use supportmapfragment and extend fragmentactivity but soo crash!

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <fragment
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

Comment: @user3703052 what is this `setContent(r.activity_main)`. post the activity code

Comment: @user3703052 can you post the activity code pls so that we can help further

Comment: Check whether google play services added to build path properly.Right click on project and select properties. In the properties window on left side select Android. On the right you can see a Add button under library section. Click it and select google play services project.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use FragmentActivity. Just add below code in your XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And in your Map Activity add following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {

            initilizeMap();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }
 }
```

Comment: You can see my answer/link that i mention.

Comment: the link does not answer the question its a blog post could as well link to the official docs

Comment: Are you have Simple Google Map Code?Not Google Sample!

Comment: I added sample code link. But some users have problem with that.

Comment: @DhruvVaishnav the problem is that the link does not answer the question nor does the suggestion in your post.

Comment: @DhruvVaishnav your update is still wrong. used `SupportMapFragment` in xml while casting it to `MapFragment` in activity. Also if min sdk is 11 and below you are supposed to use `SupportMapFragment` and extend `FragmentActivity`

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

to

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
```

`FragmentActivity` is the base class for support based fragments. So if you are using `SupportMaoFragment` your Activity must extend `FragmentActivity`.

Also `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`.

Also you need to set the content of the layout to the activity

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }
```

Comment: what's FragmentActivity Import file?

Comment: @user3703052 here is the `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity` from the support library

Comment: @user3703052 does it still crash?? what happens now??